# Quantum homomorphic encryption with a classical verifier - clarifying the setting?

Tags: cryptography, blind-quantum-computing

The quantum homomorphic protocol I am discussing is in *[Urmila Mahadev (2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02130.pdf)*. The summary is that it allows a fully classical verifier to interact with a quantum prover to run a quantum circuit.

It is shown in the paper that the key ingredient is for the quantum server to be able to perform a $\text{CNOT}^s$ gate for a bit $s$ when the server is given $\text{Enc}(s)$, i.e. the classical encryption of $s$.

My questions are:

1. How does this work for single-qubit gates? Is being able to apply a $\text{CNOT}$ conditioned on an encrypted bit sufficient to perform all gates, including single qubit gates? If yes, what is the intuition behind this?
2. Related to the above, what state is the computation being performed on? The talks show the classical verifier sending $\text{Enc}(s)$ and a quantum state. Can this instead be represented as the prover performing the computation on an intial state of $\vert 0^n\rangle$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the client not to learn anything about the computation, one must "hide" the quantum state one sends to the server. This is done via a Quantum One-Time Pad:
$$\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}\ket{\psi}\to Z^zX^x\ket{\psi}$$
where $Z$ and $X$ are the corresponding Pauli gates, and $z$ and $x$ are classical bitstrings. For instance, if the $i$-th bit of $z$ is equal to $1$, we apply a $Z$ gate on the state. Otherwise we don't.

It's a well-known result that if you don't know $x$ and $z$ and have access to a single copy of the state, you don't have any information about it (this is just like the classical one-time pad). So, we know that if the server has access to such a state it can't deduce any information from it.

Now, the difficulty of Homomorphic encryption is to perform computation on encrypted data. That, we want the server to be able to prepare $Z^{z'}X^{x'}U\ket{\psi}$ while being given $Z^zX^x\ket{\psi}$ where $z'$ and $x'$ are known by the user but not by the server, and where $U$ is a unitary gate.

For instance, let us say that we want the server to apply a $Z$ gate on the state we send. We first send the server:
$$Z^zX^x\ket{\psi}$$
The server applies a $Z$ gate and send back the state:
$$Z^{z'}X^x\ket{\psi}$$
with $z'$ being equal to $z$ except on the qubit where the $Z$ gate has been applied. The client can then apply $Z^zX^x$ to end up with $Z\ket{\psi}$.

Of course, this is not a very interesting scenario: if the user is able to implement $X$ and $Z$ gate, there is no point asking the server to perform them. The logic here is that we would want to be able to perform this task but for arbitrary (potentially "hard") unitaries.

The good news is, we are only interested in a limited amount of gates. If we can show that we can perform this type of operation for a universal set of gates, then we know that we'll be able to do it for any unitary. The author then uses the fact that the Clifford gates along with the Toffoli gate form a universal set of gates. So, to put it in a nutshell, if the server is able to implement Clifford gates and the Toffoli gate, then we can perform any computation we'd like.

Clifford gates are easy enough. Let us say that the client wants to implement a Clifford gate $C$, so that it is able to recover $C\ket{\psi}$ at the end of the computation. By definition of the Clifford group, we have that:
$$CZ^zX^xC^\dagger=Z^{z'}X^{x'}$$
for some known $z'$ and $x'$, assuming $z$ and $x$ are known (note that the equality holds up to a global phase here). So if the server owns the state:
$$Z^zX^x\ket{\psi}$$
and applies a $C$ gate on it, the state becomes:
$$CZ^zX^x\ket{\psi}=Z^{z'}X^{x'}C\ket{\psi}$$
The last important point here is that the server also owns $\text{Enc}(x)$ and $\text{Enc}(z)$ and is able to compute $\text{Enc}(x')$ and $\text{Enc}(z')$ from them, since $\text{Enc}$ is a classical homomorphic scheme (which we assume has such a property).

Applying the Toffoli gate is a bit more involved, since we can't use the same trick. What the authors show in subsection 3.3.2 equation 32 is that if you know how to apply CNOT gates in a homomorphic way, then you are able to implement Toffoli gates in a homomorphic way.

So, to put it in a nutshell and to answer your questions:

1. Since we know how to implement the Clifford gates and the Toffoli one, we can perform any operation we'd like. However, it will at least take $3$ qubits, even if we wish only to perform a single-qubit rotation. The $2$ additional qubits will be used as ancillas and will return to the state $\ket{0}$ after the computation.
2. Yes, there is no need for a communication between the server and the client after each gate. The client can directly send the whole circuit to the server.

There's something one must be careful about though, which is the very first operation. If the computation starts from a state that is known to the server, it can learn the Pauli twirling, or even directly performs the computation by itself to get the desired state.

Thus, this must be thought as if the server wanted to compute a function $f(x)$. The client will tell the server to create the state $\left|x'\right\rangle=X^{x\oplus x'}|x\rangle$ and send the server $\text{Enc}\left(x\oplus x'\right)$. This is essentially a One-Time Pad, which means that the server has no information whatsoever (computationally speaking at least, since they have access to $\text{Enc}\left(x\oplus x'\right)$) on $x$.

Thanks to squiggles [for correcting me about this crucial last point](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/quantum-homomorphic-encryption-with-a-classical-verifier-clarifying-the-settin/35035?noredirect=1#comment46755_35035)!

To put it in a nutshell, here's how the protocol goes in its entirety, assuming the client wants to compute $f(x)$.

1. The client samples a random string $x'$ and tells the server to prepare the state $\left|x'\right\rangle$. The client also sends $\text{Enc}\left(x\oplus x'\right)$ to the server as its Pauli $X$-twirl. The Pauli $Z$-twirl is set to $0$.
2. If the client wants the server to apply a Clifford gate, the server can do so by applying said gate on the current state and updating the Pauli $X$ and $Z$-twirl accordingly.
3. If the client wants the server to apply a Toffoli gate, the server can also do so by the scheme presented in the paper, without the server needing to know the initial $X$ and $Z$ twirl. Once again, the server can update those twirls accordingly.
4. At the end of the computation, the server ends up with the basis state $X^y|f(x)\rangle=|f(x)\oplus y\rangle$ and the classical data $\text{Enc}(y)$. It sends both $f(x)\oplus y$ and $\text{Enc}(y)$ to the client which is thus able to recover $f(x)$.

Comment: Hey I like that answer!  I learned a lot from it!

Comment: @MarkSpinelli Thanks, it means a lot to me!

Comment: It’s the CNOT gate that uses that fancy string $d$ orthogonal to the two preimages of the claw, with $d\cdot(x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ , right?

Comment: @TristanNemoz great answer. The way Clifford gates are implemented here - does this not presume that the client has some quantum ability? That is, they must send the server $Z^zX^x\vert \psi\rangle$ and then get the server to apply a $Z$ gate on some qubit. But our client is assumed to be classical and a fully classical client cannot prepare the state $Z^zX^x\vert \psi\rangle$ - they must rely on the server to prepare this for them too. This is the part that I don't understand.

Comment: @user1936752 the classical client gives an encoding if $x$ and $z$ in the string $s$, don’t they? These are just classical numbers, right?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli, my understanding was that $s\in\{0,1\}$ was encoded classically and sent to the server. The server then applies $CNOT^s$ purely using $Enc(s)$. I don't see how the server applies, for examples $Z^z$ if it is given $z$ in some classical encoding. Do you see where this is explained in the paper?

Comment: @user1936752 I don't know for sure but I interpreted this from some of Mahadev's lectures and presentations on this topic.  Sorry I can't be more explicit!  If you find out more then perhaps add another answer for the community?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli It would appear so concerning the CNOT gate yes!

Comment: @user1936752 You're too fast for me :D I've deleted my previous comment, there's something I still don't understand about the way the scheme proceeds after all. I was going to create a chat room to discuss about it with you and Mark Spinelli if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes, let's chat about it! Apologies if I reply sporadically, I'm currently traveling. I am very interested in figuring this out though :)

Comment: @user1936752 I've added to my answer what disturbs me about this protocol. If you think you have any answer to bring regarding this point, feel free to edit the answer. Or if you're unsure about anything, please ask in the comments!

Comment: @TristanNemoz doesn't the server prepare $|x\rangle$ only up to an unknown Pauli twist?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli The thing is that if I'm not mistaken, it can learn this Pauli twist. In fact, the fact that the server prepares $|x\rangle$ *is* the Pauli twist: wlog the computation is supposed to start from the $|0\rangle$ state, $X^x=|x\rangle$ is the 
Pauli twisted version of it already. I do understand where the security comes from when the server starts with an unknown state, but the very first operation requires it not to measure the basis state it just prepared, which is undetectable by the client. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli Putting things differently, the computation has to start from a Pauli-twisted version of $|0\rangle$, since the security comes from the fact that we apply operations on a Pauli-twisted state. A Pauli-twisted $|0\rangle$ is just a basis state $|x\rangle$. If the server doesn't measure it, it only holds $\text{Enc}(x)$ and thus can't get any information and can carry the requested operations on this state. If they do however, they can outright remove the Pauli twist and get copies of the final, untwisted state by running it in parallel. Or so I think?

Comment: Sorry because I'm an interloper who hasn't read full conversation, but surely we aren't restricted to assuming that the computation starts from a Pauli-twisted version of $|{0}\rangle$? Can't the input be anything?

Comment: @squiggles For now we're talking about a purely classical client, so it would seem that we're limited to such a thing. Even if the protocol were to start from a state $|\psi\rangle$, it's the server's responsibility to prepare it, and to apply the Pauli OTP, which is basically the same problem as before.

Comment: haha sorry, my question is even more basic: when I say can't the input be anything, I mean any binary string? In that case, the server can't immediately deduce the twirl .

Comment: @squiggles Well, the client wants the server to perform a quantum computation, that is they want the result of $U|0\rangle$. So, the computation is supposed to start from the $|0\rangle$ state. Thus, receiving $|x\rangle$, the server immediately knows the twirl. Once again, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: Hm - why do they necessarily want the outcome of $U|0\rangle$? As opposed to $U|\text{some other bit string}\rangle$.

Imagine $U$ is the circuit for Shor's algorithm, and the input $|x\rangle$ is the semiprime you want to factor. The setup (I would think) of quantum homomorphic encryption would be that you'd want the quantum server to factor $x$ without revealing $x$ to the server.

I definitely agree that applying a OTP to something the adversary _knows_ started as $0$ reveals the OTP.

Comment: @squiggles You're totally right! I'll edit the answer to reflect this discussion. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am but a simple squiggle. Glad we sorted this out!

Comment: Sorry @squiggles and Tristan, I didn't catch your point. The state $X^{x\oplus x'}\vert x\rangle = X^{x'}\vert 0\rangle = \vert x'\rangle$. If the server prepares this state, they can measure it and immediately know $x'$ and still reuse the state. So what was the point of sending $Enc(x')$? Could you expand on that last part of the answer? Also, our chatroom for this question was closed but I'm happy to chat about this if you guys (and anyone else who is interested) would like to. How does one open that room again?

Comment: @user1936752 That was a typo on my part, I've corrected it. The clients sends $\text{Enc}\left(x\oplus x'\right)$ to the server. The server can learn $x'$ by measuring the state, but isn't able to learn anything about $x$, since $x'$ has been chosen at random independently of $x$. If you still have a question despite this typo being corrected, I don't mind reopening the chatroom :)

Comment: @user1936752 Essentially, the reason why I wrote $X^{x\oplus x'}|x\rangle$ in the first place was to highlight the fact that $|x\rangle$ is the state the computation must start from (the one on which we'll apply gates) and $x\oplus x'$ is the original Pauli $X$-twirl applied to the state. Thus, the client must send $\text{Enc}\left(x\oplus x'\right)$ to the server so that the server can update it later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to construct this answer! Adding a bounty (needs 24 hours before I can award it) for the insightful discussion

Comment: @user1936752 Thanks, much appreciated!